Why are there 2 [[Prototype]]s in an JS Array in VS Code's Debug Console?
I've run the following code using Node.js in VS Code
const theArray = [1,2,3];
const theObject = {'a': 1};
console.log(theArray);
console.log(theObject);
debugger; // Breakpoint

Output of Code above
My problem is that there are 2 [[Prototype]] inside theArray at the same layer. I understand that there can be a [[Prototype]] inside another but not how there can be 2 directly under theArray on the same layer. This doesn't make sense to me.
(Also the [[Prototype]] = Array(0) has 2 [[Prototype]] = Object inside it.)

The Array constructor has its own prototype object, and it inherits from the Object prototype.

Also note that the prototypes are not "inside" the object, they are in a list.

JS uses prototypical inheritance

So this is a bit weird about JavaScript. When you look deep down under the hood, everything is an object. Then, if you read a bit about Prototype Chains, it becomes apparent. This however is information that most developers wont ever use. Most JavaScript devs nowadays just pick up a framework and use it for a few years, then move on to the next new thing. It has been the same for years now, for as long as I can remember.

I suggest this article to clear things up.

This is apparently the expected behaviour. This is how the builtin debug support for JS debugging in VS Code works for prototype chains in the debug console. When you log an object, the prototype chain will be shown at the bottom (flattened in addition to being visible when you expand each prototype up the chain, which is somewhat confusing).
Examples of this in test harnesses for vscode-js-debug (the builtin extension providing that debug support) include:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/blob/a8859b0435a9e8cbfe5a123359827674fa5d9de3/src/test/variables/variables-object-simple-array.txt
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/blob/a8859b0435a9e8cbfe5a123359827674fa5d9de3/src/test/evaluate/evaluate-queryobjects.txt
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/blob/a8859b0435a9e8cbfe5a123359827674fa5d9de3/src/test/node/node-runtime-sets-arguments.txt#
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/blob/a8859b0435a9e8cbfe5a123359827674fa5d9de3/src/test/variables/variables-web-tags.txt
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/blob/a8859b0435a9e8cbfe5a123359827674fa5d9de3/src/test/browser/browser-launch-runtime-args.txt

